# Vite expose network URL cannot open in mobile devices

Tags: vite

I have run below command for expose the application to external URL for viewing in mobile devices

```
npm run dev -- --host
```

```
VITE v3.1.8  ready in 618 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:xxx/
  ➜  Network: http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/
  ➜  Network: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx/
```

The network URL is working fine when I open it in my desktop but it can't be opened in mobile devices and show "Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding" after a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

This might be late but I encountered the same thing right now. You just need to turn off your firewall on public network. Windows security -> Firewall network -> Public network.

Answer (score 0):

If using ESET antivirus on system, make sure to Unblock 'Node.js Javacscript Runtime - nodejs.exe' Network Communication from your Mobile Device connected to the network devices tab of Antivirus.